# using RStudio with self compiled R

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

How can I get RStudio to recognize my version of R which is installed to

```
/opt/R/3.4.3/
```

by compiling it myself (`make install`) and `ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R /bin/R`. When executing on a shell, R works just fine. Only RStudio does not recognize the different path and is still looking at:

```
/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/exec/R
```

exact error message:

```
Feb  3 14:50:18 devbox systemd: Starting RStudio Server...
Feb  3 14:50:18 devbox systemd: Started RStudio Server.
Feb  3 14:50:18 devbox rserver[22411]: ERROR R did not return any output when queried for directory location information; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::r_util::<unnamed>::detectRLocationsUsingR(const std::string&, rstudio::core::FilePath*, rstudio::core::FilePath*, rstudio::core::config_utils::Variables*, std::string*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/core/r_util/REnvironmentPosix.cpp:483
Feb  3 14:50:18 devbox rserver[22411]: ERROR system error 71 (Protocol error) [description=Unable to parse version from R, version-info=, r-error=/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_gf_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory|||]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::r_util::rVersion(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const std::string&, std::string*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/core/r_util/REnvironmentPosix.cpp:784; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::r_util::detectREnvironment(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const std::string&, std::string*, std::string*, rstudio::core::r_util::EnvironmentVars*, std::string*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/core/r_util/REnvironmentPosix.cpp:678
```

I realized (see answer below) that R only worked as long as I did not loose the current bash environment. Executing:

```
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
```

fixes this. However, I cant get RStudio to execute this before starting up. I played around with `ExecStartPre=/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64`, but it fails to get the environment up correctly

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, RStudio Desktop and Open-Source Server use the version of R pointed to by the output of `which R`. If RStudio is unable to locate R using which R, it will fall back to scanning explicitly for the R script in the /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin directories.

If you want to override which version of R is used then you can set the `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R` environment variable to the R executable that you want to run against. For example:

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/local/bin/R
```

See [RStudio Support: Using Different Versions of R](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R)

Comment: this is not fixing it. Only a single version of R is installed.

Comment: But as outline, that is already pointing to: `/bin/R` via the softlink.

Comment: indeed: `ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R /bin/R` as in the initial post.

Answer (score 1):

I manually need to load

```
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
```

into the environment for R to work, as otherwise links are broken and R won't start up which leads to RStudio complaining (with a not 100% helpful error message).